# How to create a temporary workspace on the personal laptop for an android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, workspace

" You have set up a temporary webspace (say on your own laptop), to which
the App connects, and fetches this data. "

"On the server side, a basic persistence mechanism (such as a JSON or XML file, or a DB like SQLite or MySQL) manages the data. The App should be able to show the current details to the user. The details must be fetched once, every time the app starts (no periodic fetches are expected). On the server side, a basic mechanism via a web based interface, must be in place to manipulate details in the persistent data (you must not change the data directly via an editor or by using utilities like MySQL command-line)."

These lines are from my assignment. What do I have to do in general?

Comment: You should have taken your course more serious. Then you had known what to do.

Comment: 3 months of course is still remaining, and the course is mostly self-study. It is the first assignment only.